# Inductive definition for number of ways to tile a $2$ by $n$ grid?

Tags: recurrence-relations, tiling

Inductive definition for number of way to tile a 2xn grid?
[image]

I have attempted to formulate an inductive definition, thinking that every extra column we add, adds an extra n-1 ways to tile the grid.
Therefore I came up with: $u_{n+1}=u_n+(n-1)$. However, this is not a second order recurrence relation, so I am not sure about the answer they are looking for. Any ideas? (I am not asking about actually solving the recurrence relation, just formulating it, hopefully I will then be able to solve it on my own!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To derive a recurrence for $u_n$, consider the only two possible ways to cover column $n$:

- One vertical domino
- Two horizontal dominoes that cover columns $n-1$ and $n$

In each case, removing the covered columns reduces to a smaller problem with the same structure as the original problem.

Comment: So for the one vertical domino, you consider the $u_{n-1}$ tilings, but for the two horizontal dominoes, do I just add $2u_{n-2}$?

Comment: Yes, $u_{n-1}$, but $2u_{n-2}$ should just be $u_{n-2}$.  Note that $u_n$ counts tilings, not dominoes.

Comment: So the inductive definition is simply the fibonacci sequence?

Comment: Yes, Fibonacci.